# Wait until operation is finished

Tags: ios

I need to wait until file is moved to a new location to use it.

In simulator this code runs fast and file is moved to a new location before I start using it, but on real device it's not.

I tried to use `@synchronized` but seems it's not the right tool.

Any advices?

```
        NSURL *newurl = [[legacyPersistentStoreURL  URLByDeletingPathExtension] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"guide"];
        NSURL *desturl = [newurl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"StoreContent"];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:desturl withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];
        NSURL *finalurl = [desturl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"persistentStore"];
        [fileManager moveItemAtURL:legacyPersistentStoreURL toURL:finalurl error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 2):

This method may help

```
- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait;
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work. 
UIManagedDocument error: The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
2012-03-13 14:39:21.371 Guides[8824:2403]   {
    reason = "Missing store file";
}

Comment: @Flink there exists some other problem in the code. you are getting NSFileReadNoSuchFileError .

Comment: It's because of file wasn't moved to a new location. Next code that use that file runs in the same time when file is moving

Comment: ok. may be you can run a busy waiting while loop checking the availability of the file. you can add a sleep value to make the loop run graciously.